Ruby Openssl RSA private_decrypt is not raising OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: padding check failed error
I am using openssl library for RSA encryption and decryption. my ruby version 2.6.10 and rails version is 5.2.8.1
version of openssl is
OpenSSL::VERSION => 2.1.2

OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION => "OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020"

Below is my code.
private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(private_key)
private_key.private_decrypt("testing", OpenSSL::PKey::RSA::PKCS1_PADDING)

Output of above code is below
"\\\xC5N\xBFNG\x02\xEB\xF7c\xAD\xB7\x04W3\xF9\xFD\xCEh\x99A\xCF7\vX2h\x99\xA9\x18\xE0\x16\xA6\xA9\xEF?)\x0E\xCE\x10\xE9JG\xD0\xA2\x91TY\xCB\xA9~\xD5xql\xF5\ac\xC5)|\x1F{\xD0\xC6om0\xAC\xB3\xD7\xEDRK\xC15\xAF\x1C\xEAb4\x8E8\xC6\xA4W\xB5R\xE4G=\xE4\xAF\xCEx\xEB\x99`Z\xEDh\xFD\xE7\xB6\x0E|4\xDEJY\xD1\x0E\xC2&\xD2\xCDvl\x89 \xE7\x11\xAA/\xDA\x00\xE0B\x0F\xF4\x8D\x98\x96D\xD6v\xE8\xF5\xAF\xF0!T\xED\x8Eg;\xF6\xF4\xBD1\x18;o^\xD0/\x80\x10\x84!d\ar\"\x17\xD3\r\x14y\xA6\x82Gb&\xEF\x85\xBF'\x13E\x83S\x0F\x83\xC5\x83\x9AP\xC6Js\xA0d\xFD*\xB4*^\xAA\xE8\x0E\xB2.\xD4\xF8\xC2\x90\x16t5\xF1<\x93K\xB4"

But when i am executing above same code in below environment same code is giving me an error OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: padding check failed
ruby 1.9.3
rails 3.2.21
OpenSSL::VERSION => "1.1.0"
OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION => "OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016"

What i don't understand is why openssl version OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020 is decrypting unencrypted data in this case "testing" ? why i am not getting OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: padding check failed error ? is anything changed between openssl version "OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016" and "OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020" ?

The reason may be a bugfix in OpenSSL 3.2 for security reasons (protection against Bleichenbacher attack), see #732, which is also backported in some environments. The latter could explain why the fix applies to you for OpenSSL::VERSION => 2.1.2, OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION => "OpenSSL 1.1.1f 31 Mar 2020", but not in this online IDE with identical OpenSSL version: https://onecompiler.com/ruby/42gsjfxw6

looks like some issue with libmysqlclient-dev .. when i removing this library it works but i am not able to install mysql gem.. checking what is the relation between openssl and libmysqlclient-dev
